# Check if url contains a word

Tags: php, url

How can I check if urls - http://www.hotek.com.ua/live/5605/forum15000/223, http://www.hotek.com.ua/5635/forum12200/223 contain words 'live' and 'forum'.

I'm trying this (like here [Check if url contains certain word then display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543554/check-if-url-contains-certain-word-then-display)) but it doesn't help.

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ((strpos($url, 'forum') !== false) or (strpos($url, 'live') !== false)){

 header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');

 echo "404 Not Found";

 exit();  
}
```

I need 404 Not Found or noindex or 301 Moved permanently to the main page just to delete these pages from Google index.

Comment: Is it just that you should be using `&&` in your condition instead of `||` ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You said it doesn't help but not what exactly is the problem, i.e. what you expected and what happened instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

> **strpos** - Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also
>   note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.

```
$str1 = "http://www.hotek.com.ua/live/5605/forum15000/223";
$str2 = "http://www.hotek.com.ua/5635/forum12200/223";

if(strpos($str1, "live") > 0 || strpos($str1, "forum") > 0 ){
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo "404 Not Found";
    exit();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if (preg_match('/forum|live/i', $actual_link)) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    //you cannot echo anything else after header or you'll get an error
    exit();
}
```

---

> I need 404 Not Found or noindex or 301 Moved permanently to the main
>   page just to delete these pages from Google index.

You can also ask google to remove the urls by going to :

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal

---

References:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en